# Turtle graphics, draw a filled star?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to draw a filled-in star, such as:

[image: http://www.seaviewstickers.co.uk/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/600x600/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/l/black_11.jpg]

I have this code so far:

```
def draw_star(size,color):
    count = 0
    angle = 144
    while count <= 5:
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)
        count += 1
    return

draw_star(100,"purple")
```

I want to fill in the star with whatever color the function is passed. How can I do this?

Comment: you've got an out-by-one error. One side will be drawn twice

Answer (score 4):

To get a 5 pointed star, you should draw 2 lines for each side. The angles need to add to 72 (360/5)

```
import turtle
def draw_star(size, color):
    angle = 120
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for side in range(5):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(72 - angle)
    turtle.end_fill()
    return

draw_star(100, "purple")
```

Experiment with different values of `angle` to get the shape you want

Comment: I like the look of this solution, but I've an issue with the `size` parameter -- what is it in relation to?  I think of `size` being the radius of a circle, for example, that the star should fit within.  However in this implementation, the size of the image changes with **both** `angle` and `size` so it's tricky to size correctly.

Comment: I added a comment to the turtle end_fill doc that overlapped regions may or may not be filled by, depending upon os graphics, the nature of the overlap, and the number of overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, you can probably get away with:

```
turtle.color("purple")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(100, extent=720, steps=5)
turtle.end_fill()
```

However, this code has two problems: it isn't the same *style* star as your illustration; it doesn't work the same on all Python turtle/tkinter implementations (some only show partial fill):

[image]

Here's an alternate implementation using *stamping* instead of *drawing* that should fix both issues:

```
STAR_SIZE = 100

EXPANSION = 1.2
TRANSLATION = STAR_SIZE * EXPANSION / 4

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color("purple")
turtle.shape("triangle")
turtle.turtlesize(STAR_SIZE * EXPANSION / 20)

for _ in range(5):
    turtle.right(72)
    turtle.forward(TRANSLATION)
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.backward(TRANSLATION)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with [`turtle.fill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.fill). However, if you just use that in your code without further change, you’ll get an “alternating” fill:

[image: alternating fill]

You’ll need to adapt your routine to draw the star’s outline without intersecting lines (can be done by alternating between two angles), or fill the inside of the star separately (by tracing the inscribed polygon).

Comment: Doesn’t give me an alternating fill.

Comment: @poke It absolutely should, look at my screenshot. The code in Eric’s answer does the same.

Comment: Well, I used both OP’s code with an added `turtle.fill(True)` at the beginning and also Eric’s code and neither gives me this result. They both show the lines going through the star but the fill is complete.

Comment: @poke That’s interesting: it probably depends on how the turtle graphics are implemented by the system then. I’m using OS X, and its libtk. I’m assuming that there must be a difference in how TK implements this operation on different systems.

Comment: Probably. I’m on Windows, tried both Python 2.7 and 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "fill" in the [turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html):

```
def draw_star(size,color):
    count = 0
    angle = 144
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)
    turtle.end_fill()

draw_star(100,"purple")
```

N.B. The `return` wasn superfluous, and by coding the loop like this it won't draw the outline twice.

Comment: On some systems, this exhibits the "alternating" fill issue that @KonradRudolph describes in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

def draw_star(size, color):
    turtle.reset()
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.lt(260)
    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.lt(170)
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.rt(100)
    turtle.end_fill()
    
draw_star(100, "purple")
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This doesn't look anything like the OP's example star.  The `fillcolor()` call is redundant with the preceding `.color()` call.  Please explain in your answer what this solution adds to the existing discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
turtle.write("★", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
```

This is just writing to turtle though so this may not help but you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *
hideturtle()

def draw_star(sidesize, points, alfacorner, color):
    betacorner = 360/points+alfacorner
    fillcolor(color)
    begin_fill()
    for x in range(points*2):
        forward(sidesize)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            left(180-alfacorner)
        else:
            right(180-betacorner)
    end_fill()


draw_star(70, 8, 90, 'grey')
draw_star(90, 5, 72, 'yellow')
draw_star(120, 5, 36, 'red')
draw_star(65, 6, 60, 'darkblue')
draw_star(80, 4, 45, 'darkviolet')
draw_star(80, 3, 30, 'greenyellow')

exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to draw a filled triangle, then pivot about the circle:

```py
from turtle import Turtle


def triangle(n):
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(n / 3)
    t.left(108)
    t.forward(n)
    t.left(144)
    t.forward(n)
    t.left(108)
    t.forward(n / 3)
    t.left(90)


def star(n):
    t.left(18)
    t.dot(n / 10)

    for _ in range(5):
        t.begin_fill()
        triangle(n)
        t.end_fill()
        t.left(360 / 5)


t = Turtle()
#t.getscreen().tracer(0)  # add if you want instantaneous drawing
star(100)
t.getscreen().exitonclick()
```

This avoids the undefined intersecting polygon mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316604/6243352). In fact, this approach is basically a non-stamp version of that answer.

Now, OP's star has a "fatter" quality to it. You can adjust the turns and movements in your `triangle()` function to beef up the star, or make it spikier (angles need to add up to 360):

```py
def triangle(n):
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(n / 2)
    t.left(120)
    t.forward(n)
    t.left(120)
    t.forward(n)
    t.left(120)
    t.forward(n / 2)
    t.left(90)


def star(n):
    t.dot(n / 10)
    t.left(18)

    for _ in range(5):
        t.begin_fill()
        triangle(n)
        t.end_fill()
        t.left(360 / 5)
```

There's room for improvement and generalization here, left as an exercise.

Answer (score -1):

```
def create_star (pointer, color_mix, central_point_x_value,\
                    central_point_y_value, length, height):
    travel_distance = length * .223
    pointer.home() # resets the orientation of the pointer
    #   without reseting everything
    pointer.penup()

    pointer.goto (central_point_x_value,central_point_y_value)
    pointer.left(90)
    pointer.forward(height) #move to the top of the star
    pointer.left(18) # must straighten the direction to match the iteration needs
    #draw Star , going counterclockwise
    # starting at the top and ending at the top of each outside triangle
    pointer.pendown()
    pointer.fillcolor (color_mix)
    pointer.begin_fill()
    count = 5
    while count != 0:
        #draw the star
        pointer.left(144)
        pointer.forward(travel_distance)
        pointer.right(72)
        pointer.forward(travel_distance)

        count -=1
    pointer.end_fill()
```

Comment: Could you explain your parameters.  If I create a circle of radius 50 in the middle of my screen and then do: `create_star(turtle.Turtle(), "purple", 0, 0, 100, 100)` I was expecting a star in the middle of my screen that "fills" my circle -- instead I get a star half the size of my circle sitting above my circle.

Answer (score -1):

I made this quick, this can easily be more corrected. Feel free to comment a better solution :)

```
import turtle 

x = turtle.Turtle()
x.speed(0)

 def draw_star(length, angle):

 for i in range(5): #the star is made out of 5 sides
  x.forward(length)
  x.right(angle)


for i in range(1):
 x.color("purple") #if  you want outline of the star choose .color("purple" + "outline color")
 x.begin_fill()
 draw_star(100, 144) #144 is the perfect angle for a star
 x.end_fill()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work, feel free to ask any questions!

```
def draw_star(size,color):
    count = 0
    angle = 144
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    while count <= 5:
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)
        count += 1
    turtle.end_fill()
    return

draw_star(100,"purple")
```

Comment: This doesn't work on some systems (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill)) and has already been posted by others.

Answer (score -2):

```
        ...:def draw_star(size):
        ...:     turtle.reset()
        ...:     turtle.color("silver")
        ...:     turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
        ...:     turtle.begin_fill()
        ...:     turtle.lt(260)
        ...:     for _ in range(5):
        ...:         turtle.fd(size)
        ...:         turtle.lt(170)
        ...:         turtle.fd(size)
        ...:         turtle.rt(100)
        ...:     turtle.end_fill()
        ...:
```

draw_star(put a size here)

Comment: what is this `...:` supposed to mean?

Comment: This doesn't work on some systems (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill)) and has already been posted by others.

Comment: Actually, this is identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268017/6243352), posted twice by the same answerer. I've edited that answer to remove the `...:`s, so this one should be deleted.