# Python Turtle is not filling alternate overlapping areas of a shape with same color

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Alternate overlapping areas of shape are not getting filled with same color. But instead its white.

Sample code

```
from turtle import *
color('black', 'yellow')    
begin_fill()
circle(40)
circle(60)
circle(80)
end_fill()
```

Why is not completely getting filled by same color ??

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. If I run your code, I get 3 circles which all get filled yellow once the turtle stops moving. [See it here. (Goes to i.ibb.co)](https://i.ibb.co/KjwsLxj/stackanswer.png)

Comment: There might be an issue with your turtle interpreter, or with how you're viewing it. If you add mainloop() at the end of the code, you can see the final image for as long as you want, if that helps.

Comment: @aargon. I am expecting as your image but what I am seeing is different. I am using ubuntu@python3.7.4  https://ibb.co/jG0bCBz

Comment: I believe this problem has come up before in the context of [filling a star](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316604/5771269).  The tkinter underpinnings in Unix and Windows environments differ on how overlapping fill is handled.

Comment: Duplicate. The graphics systems of Unix and Windows handle filling of self-intersecting polygons differently.  (Not well documented.) On Windows, if one draws a line from the outside to a particular region without going through an intersection, each line crossing toggles 'fill', starting with 'off' in the outside.  Side note: Spencer-Brown's "Laws of Form" derives boolean algebra from the observation that repetition can either confirm or negate.

Comment: The difference between Windows and Unix seems to be reversed for separate overlapping items, as in this question.  Your post on bugs.python.org indicates that you are using Ubuntu.  On Windows, the circles are all filled in, while the middle circle is not on Ubuntu and macOS.

Comment: I think this behavior is worth documenting to avoid confusion

Comment: Paragraph added in https://bugs.python.org/issue39392.