# Why does the 'turtle star' in docs.python.org not work?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to learn turtle from https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html, but I find something different from the example there.

Here is the example image:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLl6p.jpg)
and the code:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

I run the code above in my machine, but I get this:
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWyME.png).

I want to know why I can't get the example's result, and how to draw the same image.

Comment: I can't embed pictures in my ask, please follow the link to see images, sorry for that.

Comment: Likely has something to do with your systems graphics interface. What python version are you running and on what platform?

Comment: [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue39392#msg360660) explains in a bit more detail. And see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811915/python-turtle-is-not-filling-alternate-overlapping-areas-of-a-shape-with-same-co).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle graphics, draw a star?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356543/turtle-graphics-draw-a-star)

Comment: See also [Python 3.12 turtle empty inside of polygons that were filled in 3.11 with same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77693070/python-3-12-turtle-empty-inside-of-polygons-that-were-filled-in-3-11-with-same-c/77694010#77694010). It's funny that the first example Python turtle docs shows exhibits undefined/system-dependent behavior, [by their own admission](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.begin_fill:

> Whether or not overlap regions for self-intersecting polygons or
> multiple shapes are filled depends on the operating system graphics,
> type of overlap, and number of overlaps. For example, the Turtle star
> above may be either all yellow or have some white regions.