# Draw a star with turtle in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Initially, I needed to draw flowers using stars with a random number of branches. So, I wrote this function:

```py
def star(nb_branches:int , size:int) :
    for i in range(int(nb_branches / 2)) :
        forward(size * 3)
        left(180 - (360 / nb_branches))
```

(the arguments of this function are random and are created in another function but that is not the problem)

However, I realised that when the number of branches were odd, the star wasn't a perfect star. I think the loop and/or the angle are the source of this problem. Since, I tried different angles and possibilities but I didn't obtain yet the answer.

Here is an example of what I got from this function with odd numbers [image]

Comment: Related: [Turtle graphics, draw a star?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356543/turtle-graphics-draw-a-star?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about the differentiation between the odd and even numbers when I realized that my initial code worked well with even numbers, but with the half of branches. So, I took your function for the odd numbered stars and I intentionally doubled the number of branches for the even numbered stars to achieve it. Finally, I added a last `forward` to close the star.
Here is the function :

```py
def star(nb_branches:int , size:int) :
    if(nb_branches % 2 == 0) :
        nb_branches *= 2
        for i in range(nb_branches) :
            forward(size * 3)
            left(180 - (360 / nb_branches))
        forward(size * 3 / 2)
    else :
        for i in range(nb_branches) :
            forward(size * 3)
            left(180 - (180 / nb_branches))
        forward(size * 3 / 2)
```

There are surely some improvements to be made, but it works !

Answer (score 2):

Running your function looks to me like an unfinished star. Therefore I changed the loop to

```
def star(nb_branches:int , size:int) :
    for i in range(int(nb_branches *2)) : # <-- changed the range
        forward(size * 3)
        left(180 - (360 / nb_branches))
```

Since I understood `nb_branches` as the number of tips of the star, this results in a star of twice the desired tips, though.

Therefore I suggest the following function

```
from turtle import *

def star(nb_branches:int , size:int) :
    for i in range(int(nb_branches)) : # <-- halved the range
        forward(size * 3)
        left(180 - (180 / (nb_branches))) # <-- adjusted the angle per step
# testcase
star(11, 50)
```

This however does not work for even `nb_branches`. The reason is, that already after half the drawn edges the shape is closed. In order to draw even numbered stars one would need to reposition the turtle after half the interations and then draw a second shape.

Comment: If only it was possible to execute code based on the condition if a number was odd or even...